# Angularjs: Ajax works 2x. Please Help me

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ajax worked 2x.
please see this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check if you are not setting ng-controller inside the template too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a function inside the template, it generally will run twice times. That is the way AngularJS ensures the function was ran.

[You can see the same happening in this JSFIddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/U3pVM/19526/)

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
      {{hey()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.hey = function() {
    console.log('here i am');   
  }
}
```

### So, what to do?

Do not load the data using a function in the template, load it directly when the controller is initialized. [As in this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/iagomelanias/U3pVM/19528/)

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get(...);
}
```

***PS:*** are you not using the get method from jQuery, yep? Please. AngularJS has your own http methods. [See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).